# Using mediafilesegmenter on a video with edit lists

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I'm trying to use mediafilesegmenter on a video I transcoded with ffmpeg to package it for HLS. However, it complains about "edit lists" and refuses to do anything. Does anyone know how to either remove edit lists or to get mediafilesegmenter to work with them?

```
$ mediafilesegmenter -I -f 180 -t 9 -s bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.676: Using floating point is not backward compatible to iOS 4.1 or earlier devices
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.677: Single file output is not backward compatible to earlier than iOS 5.0
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.677: Processing file /Users/aspera/git/dash-demo/video-transcoding/bbb-transcoded-hls/bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.689: track 1 of /Users/aspera/git/dash-demo/video-transcoding/bbb-transcoded-hls/bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4 contains edit lists; these tracks cannot be used for segmentation
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.689: no tracks found!
Jun 29 2016 17:12:33.689: average bit rate is  0.00 bits/sec - max file bit rate is  0.00 bits/sec
```

The input video:

```
$ ffprobe bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4 
ffprobe version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    artist          : Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    comment         : Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    genre           : Animation
  Duration: 00:10:34.53, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 184 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 113 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

EDIT:
I've discovered that ffmpeg seems to add edit lists when transcoding.

Original file:

```
$ MP4Box -info originals/bbb_sunflower_2160p_60fps_normal.mp4 
* Movie Info *
    Timescale 600 - 3 tracks
    Computed Duration 00:10:34.533 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.533
    Fragmented File: no
    File suitable for progressive download (moov before mdat)
    File Brand isom - version 1
    Created: GMT Tue Dec 17 16:40:26 2013
    Modified: GMT Tue Dec 17 16:40:26 2013

File has root IOD (9 bytes)
Scene PL 0xff - Graphics PL 0xff - OD PL 0xff
Visual PL: ISO Reserved Profile (0x15)
Audio PL: Not part of MPEG-4 audio profiles (0xfe)
No streams included in root OD

iTunes Info:
    Name: Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    Artist: Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    Comment: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    Composer: Jan Morgenstern
    Writer: Sacha Goedegebure
    Genre: Animation
1 UDTA types: meta (1) 

Track # 1 Info - TrackID 1 - TimeScale 60000
Media Duration 00:10:34.533 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.533
Media Info: Language "und (und)" - Type "vide:avc1" - 38072 samples
Visual Track layout: x=0 y=0 width=3840 height=2160
MPEG-4 Config: Visual Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x21
AVC/H264 Video - Visual Size 3840 x 2160
    AVC Info: 1 SPS - 1 PPS - Profile High @ Level 5.1
    NAL Unit length bits: 32
    Pixel Aspect Ratio 1:1 - Indicated track size 3840 x 2160
    SPS#1 hash: 73C3B5E51841EEDF280132A1F7C72DD97D9FDE86
    PPS#1 hash: EB72205FBA0E2A677BE65E145507E2E05750EB4F
Self-synchronized
    RFC6381 Codec Parameters: avc1.640033
    Average GOP length: 184 samples

Track # 2 Info - TrackID 2 - TimeScale 48000
Media Duration 00:10:34.200 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.200
Media Info: Language "und (und)" - Type "soun:mp4a" - 26425 samples
MPEG-4 Config: Audio Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x6b
MPEG-1 Audio - 2 Channel(s) - SampleRate 48000 - Layer 3
Synchronized on stream 1
    RFC6381 Codec Parameters: mp4a.6b
    All samples are sync

Track # 3 Info - TrackID 3 - TimeScale 48000
Media Duration 00:10:34.144 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.144
Media Info: Language "und (und)" - Type "soun:ac-3" - 19817 samples
    AC-3 stream - Sample Rate 48000 - 5.1 channel(s) - bitrate 32000
    RFC6381 Codec Parameters: ac-3
    All samples are sync
```

After FFMPEG:

```
$ MP4Box -info bbb_180p_30fps_264k.mp4 
* Movie Info *
    Timescale 1000 - 2 tracks
    Computed Duration 00:10:34.600 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.534
    Fragmented File: no
    File Brand isom - version 512
    Created: UNKNOWN DATE   Modified: UNKNOWN DATE
File has no MPEG4 IOD/OD

iTunes Info:
    Name: Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    Artist: Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    Comment: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    Writer: Sacha Goedegebure
    Genre: Animation
    Encoder Software: Lavf57.25.100
1 UDTA types: meta (1) 

Track # 1 Info - TrackID 1 - TimeScale 15360
Media Duration 00:10:34.533 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.533
Track has 2 edit lists: track duration is 00:10:34.600
Media Info: Language "und (und)" - Type "vide:avc1" - 19036 samples
Visual Track layout: x=0 y=0 width=320 height=180
MPEG-4 Config: Visual Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x21
AVC/H264 Video - Visual Size 320 x 180
    AVC Info: 1 SPS - 1 PPS - Profile Baseline @ Level 3
    NAL Unit length bits: 32
    Pixel Aspect Ratio 1:1 - Indicated track size 320 x 180
    SPS#1 hash: 4FD0A6F8F73D905B5A9973F02BF9E2D401820F71
    PPS#1 hash: E79F98332B320CB0B190539E0D4A262181656B90
Self-synchronized
    RFC6381 Codec Parameters: avc1.42c01e
    Average GOP length: 90 samples

Track # 2 Info - TrackID 2 - TimeScale 48000
Media Duration 00:10:34.221 - Indicated Duration 00:10:34.221
Track has 1 edit lists: track duration is 00:10:34.200
Media Info: Language "und (und)" - Type "soun:mp4a" - 29730 samples
MPEG-4 Config: Audio Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x40
MPEG-4 Audio AAC LC - 2 Channel(s) - SampleRate 48000
Synchronized on stream 1
    RFC6381 Codec Parameters: mp4a.40.2
Alternate Group ID 1
    All samples are sync
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MP4 won't skip the `edts` boxes when creating MP4s. You should transcode to MPEG-TS and feed that into mediafilesegmenter

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -<transcoding options> -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb out.ts
```

Comment: I tried with no options (just ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb out.ts) but running mediafilesegmenter on out.ts only produced audio. I had to add "-c:v copy -c:a copy" to the ffmpeg command to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Mulvya's approach, but another method that "fixes" the problem is to demux and mux the streams:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -an video.mkv
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vn -c:a copy audio.mkv
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy in2.mp4
mediafilesegmenter -I -t 9 -s in2.mp4
```

I can't tell you why it works though.